# How can I clone my Windows 7 hard drive to an SSD that previously had Windows 8 installed?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, mbr

I recently bought a new SSD, and decided to create a fresh install of Windows 8 on it. I quickly decided that Windows 8 wasn't for me, so what I decided to do instead was simply clone my existing hard drive (with Windows 7 on it) to the SSD.

However I forgot about things like the MBR and whatnot. So when I try to boot from the SSD, it gives me an error, because it seems to think it's Windows 8, even though it's really a clone of my hard drive with Windows 7 now. I'm guessing this is because the MBR wasn't updated or something to that effect.

My question is, how do I fix it so I can go ahead and boot Windows 7 from my SSD? I don't mind if the solution involves cloning the original hard drive again, as all of that data is still there on the hard drive.

Comment: wouldn't it be faster and probably a lot less work to just reinstall windows 7?

Comment: I don't want to spend all weekend reinstalling all my programs and setting everything back up. Not to mention that My Windows 7 is an upgrade, so I'd need to install Vista and then install Windows 7. Anyway, cloning the disk is no problem - just press a button- I only need to know how to handle the MBR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by booting from the Windows 7 DVD, going to command prompt, and doing bootrec /rebuildbcd.

I followed [these steps](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/rebuild-bcd-store-windows.htm) to solve the issue.